# How to change visibility using binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using MVVM Light WPF 4.

I have a ContentPresenter in my Home.xaml.

```
<ContentPresenter Name="MDI" Content="{Binding WindowName, Mode=OneWay}">
```

I am binding user control to this in viewmodel like

```
public UserControl WindowName { get; set; }
    void ShowSalesEntry()
    {
        WindowName = null;
        WindowName = new SalesEntry();
        RaisePropertyChanged("WindowName");
    }
```

by using command in a menu click and it is binding fine.

Now in the user control i have a button which i used to close (but to close i change the visibility
to collapsed) by this way..

```
Visibility="{Binding visibility, Mode=OneWay}"
```

in the user control view model,

```
public SalesEntryViewModel()
    {
        visibility = Visibility.Visible;            
        cmdExitWindow = new RelayCommand(ExitWindow);
        RaisePropertyChanged("visibility");
    }
```

and the following to close (visibility to collapsed)

```
public RelayCommand cmdExitWindow { get; set; }

    void ExitWindow()
    {
        visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        RaisePropertyChanged("visibility");
    }
```

To exit (means visibility collapsed)..
This is working fine upto this.

Problem is when i click the same page i mean to show the same user control,
now this time the visibility is still collapsed. Even though i changed to visible in the
load event.

How to solve this..
I am new to MVVM WPF.. Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is when i click the same page i mean to show the same user
>   control, now this time the visibility is still collapsed. Even though
>   i changed to visible in the load event.

Based on this comment and the code provided, you've either omitted code, or you've confused the purpose of the constructor.

In your constructor, you have set the Visibility to `Visible`. You then have a method that sets the Visibility to `Hidden`, but there is nothing to ever set it back to `Visible` once this has occurred. The constructor only fires when the object is created. You need something to set the Visibility back at the appropriate time (ie. your comment "*when i click the same page*").

```
//Add these lines to the method/event that will show the control again
visibility = Visibility.Visible;
RaisePropertyChanged("visibility");
```

That's the best answer I can give based on what you've provided.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply.. But when i click the menu again and i re initialize the object right `
        WindowName = null;
        WindowName = new SalesEntry();
        RaisePropertyChanged("WindowName");` This way..
Am i wrong ?

Comment: are you actually creating a new instance of SalesEntryViewModel somewhere?  it looks like you make a new window buy are using the same viewModel without ever setting visibility to visible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Shan, and good point T. If they are drawing off the same view model (for example, the view model instance is declared in app.xaml or another shared resource dictionary) then you certainly will get this result regardless of constructing a new object.